# OpenCV imread not working on Android

Tags: android, opencv, imread

I have a C++ project using OpenCV that I need to use on Android. To simplify, let's say that this is the project code:

Test.h:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:

    Test();
    ~Test();

    static std::string getTest(std::string filePath);
};
```

---

Test.cpp:

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "Test.h"

using namespace cv;

std::string Test::getSize(std::string filePath)
{
    Mat image = imread(filePath, 1);

    std::stringstream stringStream;

    if(image.empty())
    {
        stringStream << "Error loading image at path: " << filePath;
        std::string error = stringStream.str();

        return error;
    }

    stringStream << "Image size: " << image.rows << " * " << image.cols;
    std::string result = stringStream.str();

    return result;
}
```

I wrote my JNI bindings and set up my Android.mk and it compiles, but the imread method does not work: the image is empty (the image.empty() test is true).

What can be wrong here? I checked that the file exists, so I guess that it is either:

- a permission problem (I added the read/write external storage permissions, but it may be lower level issues)
- a file path problem. I provided an absolute file path (like "/storage/emulated/0/test.jpg"). Does OpenCV expect a relative path? If so, relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, it was just that I did not accept the storage permission on the Android 7 phone -_-